# Prolog recursive implementation of arithmetic average / mean

Tags: prolog, average

I am trying to implement a recursive function to compute the
arithmetic average of a given list in [Prolog](https://swish.swi-prolog.org/) based on following formula:

[image]
[Source: Recursive Arithmetic Average](http://www.cargalmathbooks.com/32%20Averages%20.pdf)

**Database:**

```
avg([],0,_).
avg([X|L],Anew,Nnew) :-
    avg(L,A,N),
    Anew is (N * A + X) / Nnew,
    Nnew is N+1.
```

**Query:**

```
?- avg([5.0, 6.0, 7.0, 8.0], A, N).
```

Expected output:

```
A = 6.5
```

Unfortunately, I am stuck since quite some time and after trying a few variations, I am getting following error now:

```
Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

I am grateful for any Hints, Links, References, etc.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Switch the order of the last 2 clauses; Prolog needs all of the variables in an arithmetic expression to be instantiated before it can satisfy an `is`.

Also, you'll to supply `N` *somewhere* (base case is a good spot).

Comment: Thank you so much, it work now after redefining the base-case to `avg([],0,0).` and switching the lines of `Anew` and `Nnew`!